# _signTypedData method on ethers does not match with ERC712 solidity code

Tags: solidity, signature, openzeppelin

I've faced an ethers signature unmatched problem.

Everything is normal.
Already compared `domainData`, `types`, `message` variable in the js code with contract.

Below is the JS Code to generate signature and call contract.

```
      const contractAddress = await contract.address;

      domainData.chainId = 31337;
      domainData.verifyingContract = contractAddress;

      const signature = await signer._signTypedData(domainData, types, message);
      const { r, s, v } = ethers.utils.splitSignature(signature);

      const result = await contract.recoverAddressFromTypedData(
        message,
        v,
        r,
        s
      );
      expect(result).to.equal(signer.address);
```

Below is the solidity code which use "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/draft-EIP712.sol"

```
function recoverAddressFromTypedData(
    Bid memory bid,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s
) public view returns (address) {
    bytes32 digest = _hashTypedDataV4(hashBid(bid));
    address signer = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
    return signer;
}
```

But I got following error on the last line of JS code.

```
AssertionError: expected '0x7Da34C07B95dB4A1c85fe4C5d313F4860E85e340' to equal '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266'
      + expected - actual

      -0x7Da34C07B95dB4A1c85fe4C5d313F4860E85e340
      +0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have the same reason as you, in my case I had a struct member containing a string type which needed to be converted to bytes32.

```
contract MyContract is Ownable, AccessControl, EIP712 {
    struct Action {
        address initiator;
        string name;
    }
    bytes32 public constant ACTION_TYPE_HASH = keccak256("Action(address initiator,string name)");
    function _hashStruct(Action memory action) private pure returns (bytes32) {
        // If your struct member has string type,
        // you need to use keccak256(abi.encodePacked(string))
        // convert it to bytes32
        return keccak256(abi.encode(ACTION_TYPE_HASH, action.initiator, keccak256(abi.encodePacked(action.name))));
    }
    function _hashTypedDataV4(Action memory action) private view returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 structHash = _hashStruct(action);
        return EIP712._hashTypedDataV4(structHash);
    }
    // more...
}
```

[image: code.png]